# Autofixup consecutive commits of same message and author (of the complete repo)

Tags: git, git-svn, rebase, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I have migrated a big SVN repository to GIT and there are tons of consecutive commits with the same message of the same author.

Now I would like to automatically fixup the commits into one single commit.

Thoughts?

Comment: I assume you don't want to keep the repository functional for pushing changes into the old SVN repository?

Comment: @Zeeker No it's migrated - so the SVN server will go down

Comment: I'm currently on my Smartphone, so I can't write an extensive answer. You can either take a look for yourself at `git filter-branch` or wait until I got time to write up an answer.

Comment: It can wait over the weekend ;)

Comment: Just wanted to say that I didn't forget about you. I'm fighting with some weird problems probably related with the fact I'm working on windows. May I ask on which OS and with which Git version you're working?

Comment: I'm on Debian with git 1.7.10.4

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to nail the problem down, as usual it was a human error.

The script I provide here is written for bash, but as I can see from your experiment this shouldn't be a problem.

This is the script, I will explain it in detail below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

author="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME <$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL>"
msg="$(cat)"
tree="$1"
parents=()
shift
while getopts ":p:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        p)
            parents=(${parents[*]} $OPTARG)
            ;;
        ?)
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done


create_parents_option() {
    parentsstring=""
    for parent in $@; do
        parentsstring+="-p $parent "
    done
    echo "$parentsstring"
}

get_msg() {
    git log -1 --format="%B" $1
}

get_author() {
    git log -1 --format="%aN <%aE>" $1
}

squash_commit() {
    if [ "x$author" == "x$(get_author $1)" ] && [ "x$msg" == "x$(get_msg $1)" ]; then
        git read-tree -m --aggressive ${1}^{tree} $tree >/dev/null
        tree=$(git write-tree)
        parents=($(git log --format=%P -1 $1))
    fi
}

if [[ ${#parents[@]} == 1 ]]; then
    squash_commit ${parents[0]}
fi

git commit-tree $tree $(create_parents_option ${parents[@]}) -m "$msg"
```

You can execute the script via:

```sh
git filter-branch --commit-filter "$(cat /path/to/the/script)"
```

---

The script will check if the current commit was commited by the same author and with the same message as before.

If that's he case it will merge the trees of the current commit with the changes of the commit before using `git read-tree -m` which merges the given trees and writes the result into the index.
Afterwards `git write-tree` is used to produce a new tree from the merged result on the index.

Then the script continues by setting the parent of the current commit onto the parent of the parent of the merged commit, effectively "removing" this commit from the history.

If you have any further questions I'm glad to help. It was fun working on this!

**Edit:** I've tested this script on Windows 7 with msysgit version 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first version but it needs some more tests and I'm sure it could be much smarter:

```
#!/bin/bash

git filter-branch --force --prune-empty --tree-filter 'GIT_PARANT=$(git log -n 2 $GIT_COMMIT --pretty=format:"%h" | wc -l); if [ "$GIT_PARANT" = "1" ]; then GIT_SUBJECT=$(git log -n 1 $GIT_COMMIT --pretty=format:"%s" | sed -e "s/ \\+/ /g" -e "s/^ *//" -e "s/ *\$//"); GIT_LAST_SUBJECT=$(git log -n 1 $GIT_COMMIT~1 --pretty=format:"%s" | sed -e "s/ \\+/ /g" -e "s/^ *//" -e "s/ *\$//"); GIT_LAST_AUTHOR=$(git log -n 1 $GIT_COMMIT~1 --pretty=format:"%an <%ae>"); GIT_LAST_COMMITTER=$(git log -n 1 $GIT_COMMIT~1 --pretty=format:"%cn <%ce>"); echo "\n - test subject: $GIT_SUBJECT <-> $GIT_LAST_SUBJECT\n - test author: $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME <$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL> <-> $GIT_LAST_AUTHOR\n - test committer: $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME <$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL> <-> $GIT_LAST_COMMITTER"; if [ "$GIT_SUBJECT" = "$GIT_LAST_SUBJECT" ] && [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME <$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL>" = "$GIT_LAST_AUTHOR" ] && [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME <$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL>" = "$GIT_LAST_COMMITTER" ];  then git reset $GIT_COMMIT~1; else echo "...pick"; fi; else echo "\n...pick"; fi' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

@Zeeker I already started experiments and don't know your way / state - this answer isn't accepted yet!